# Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3. Done. Nothing was installed

Tags: android, sdk

I have installed eclipse, sdk manager and JDK on my system having windows 8. Now i am trying to install various platforms on SDK manager. But i get this error:

Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3

Download interrupted: peer not authenticated.

Done. Nothing was installed.

Comment: http://support.pluralsight.com/knowledgebase/articles/47311-i-am-having-trouble-logging-on-to-the-android-app-

Comment: @Shark thnx a ton :))

Comment: next time google for 2 mins before posting :) i literally copy/pasted your error into upper-right corner and clicked 'im feeling lucky'.

Comment: FYI, on my side, download works from Android SDK Manager, but NOT from within eclipse Menu 'Android Tools' -> 'Add Support Library', which lead to the 'Download interrupted: peer not authenticated.' error. (Mac OS 10.9)